# play logging level for logback

Tags: playframework, sbt, slf4j, logback

I'm trying to set logging level to debug in play application.

I am able to create a `logger.xml` file and place it in `conf` directory and see the debug statements printed out after I run `sbt run` and do some clicks on the app, that run through the code with debug statements.

On the other hand, when I package the app with `sbt dist`, I don't see any output from the application when the code with the debug logging is executed.

I can see, that the `logger.xml` is on the classpath, it is a part of one of the jars in the lib directory.

What do I need to set to be able to configure logging for the packaged application?

Comment: For what it's worth, logback logging does work if you use "sbt stage"; I haven't been able to find the difference between "sbt stage" and "sbt dist" that would cause the latter to not have logging in production.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, we've never tried running our apps with the logger file baked in. We've always run it by having the logger settings file on the box and passing it in as a param when starting up the app using the -Dlogger.file option as described here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/SettingsLogger

You don't happen to have something passing that argument in at runtime that is overriding your one already on classpath? Per this doc (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/Configuration) and the accepted Java standard, a passed in property will take priority over what it was compiled with.

You might just double check the start script the dist command creates to see if that argument was specified and what it is set to.